# "without offence" in German

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

How would you authentically say in German "without offence" in the meaning that I don't want to hurt the counterpart's feelings?

Comment: Please provide more context. "ohne ihnen zu nahe treten zu wollen" could fit.

Comment: I think the idiomatic English expression would be "no offense", no offense.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom "*Nichts für ungut*" in the sense of "No harm meant", "No hard feelings" might be an option.

Couple of examples from the Internet:

***Nichts für ungut**, aber die Ehe von Iolo und Gwenno ist einfach ein Witz* - [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=nichts%20f%C3%BCr%20ungut)

*Äh, Mac, **nichts für ungut**, aber wir sollten jetzt vielleicht mal langsam ..*. - [dwds.de](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=nichts%20f%C3%BCr%20ungut&corpus=kern&h=1&from=wb)

***Nichts für ungut**, aber das Kleid steht dir ganz und gar nicht!*- [de.wiktionary.org](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nichts_f%C3%BCr_ungut)

I am not sure how frequent this is in modern usage, any update from native speakers would be welcome.

Comment: While the phrase has an old touch, I don't see an obvious replacement. *Entschuldigung* may also fit depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

In everyday speech, it is common to say:

- "Entschuldigung, aber ..."
- "Tut mir leid, aber ..."
- "Nimm's mir nicht übel, aber ..."

More formally and a bit antiquated:

- "Ohne Ihnen zu nahe treten zu wollen, ..."
- "Nichts für ungut, ..."

Answer (score 1):

Please for the future: Please provide some full sentences as examples. You never translate words, but you always translate meanings. And the meaning of two word phrases can be very ambiguous. A proper grammatical environment can help a lot, but grammar is not the art of building fragments. Grammar is the art of building full sentences.

Here are three examples, I hope they can help you.

> The next time someone is in your way, saying "Excuse me" will get the result you want **without causing offense.**
> Wenn Ihnen das nächste Mal jemand in die Quere kommt, sagen Sie einfach "Entschuldigung" und Sie erhalten das gewünschte Ergebnis, **ohne jemanden zu beleidigen.**

> Grant to them, Lord, health, peace, concord, and stability, so that they may exercise **without offense** the sovereignty that you have given them.
> Gewähre ihnen, Herr, Gesundheit, Frieden, Eintracht und Stabilität, damit sie die ihnen von dir übertragene Herrschaft **ohne Ärgernis** ausüben können.

> After Müller and Schneider were sent to the penalty box, the team was **without offence,** which led to a dramatic defeat.
> Nachdem Müller und Schneider auf die Strafbank geschickt wurden, war die Mannschaft **ohne Angreifer,** was zu einer dramatischen Niederlage führte.

---

- without = ohne
- offence/offense = Angriff, Straftat, Vergehen, Beleidigung, Ärgernis, Anstoß, Delikt, Zuwiderhandlung, Verstoß, Delikt, Verfehlung, Verbrechen, ...

Comment: As infinitezero commented, there is an expression "no offense" which is often said when you want to say something that someone might take as offensive even it's not meant to be offensive. As you pointed out, there not much context given in the question so it's hard to tell if that's what is meant here.